# Mailx or Informatica task - send message to recipient with more than 1 name in address

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, mailx

I have a problem with email sending in informatica when i need to send a message to a person which have more than 1 word in his email. like: Pizza and Pasta@mail.ru

This email address belongs to a group of people (about 10).
When i'm writing something like this (using session in informatica and choose in components post-session succeed command) :

```
echo "Test" | mailx Pchernyakov@mail.ru, Pizza and Pasta@mail.ru -s "Loading of the report done"
```

my letter splits the **Pizza and Pasta@mail.ru** into 3 mails like
*Pizza@localhost.myjob.net, and@localhost.myjob.net, Pasta@localhost.myjob.net*

My email is correct (Pchernyakov@mail.ru) that's why i recieve a message.

This problem exists also in Email task in informatica when i fill in Email User Name like
*Pchernyakov@mail.ru; Pizza and Pasta@mail.ru*

Commas, quotation marks - doesn't work. I need an idea. Maybe, somebody has had this problem and know the solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not adding all mail ids separated by comma? email ids cant have blank space in it. Not sure about your expectation as well.

Comment: @KoushikRoy it is group of people, but not a GROUP BOX - thats why it can be with spaces ;( 
I see only 1 way in this case: add to list all personal emails of people who should recieve the message.

Comment: can you create a group with all the emails ? and use the group name in infa

Comment: It is the best way as i think, but business wants to know about possibility in this situation.

Comment: `mailx` is actually UNIX command and doesnt depend/related to infa. So, i think options can be - use infa mail output or use some hack to fix mailx behavior as per this link -https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=671295

Comment: TOTAL: mailx and other thinks doesn't help - only 1 way that we have to create a normal group box